# Error in PGI Accelerator Fortran code

Tags: cuda, fortran, openacc, pgi-accelerator

This is my code

```
program load_flow


!!!!!!!region starts 
!$acc region
p1=0;p=0
do i=2,n
    do j=1,n
        p1=(V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j)))
        p=p1+p
     end do
     P0(i-1)=p
     p=0
end do

! % % % %------Reactive Power Calculation-----%  
p=0;p1=0

do i=2,(n-m)
      do j=1,n
p1=-(V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j)))
p=p1+p
      end do
      Q0(i-1)=p
      p=0
end do

!!!!!!!!!!!mismatch factor
do i=1,(n-1)
   B1(i)=Ps(b,i)-P0(i)
  end do
do i=1,(n-m-1)
   B2(i)=Qs(b,i)-Q0(i)
end do

MF(1,1:38)=B1(1:38)
MF(1,39:67)=B2(1:29)
!!!!!!!!jacobian calculation for preddictor step
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!dia of j1
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,n
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
 p1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))

 p=p1+p
       end if

    end do
    i=i-1
    dia1(i,i)=p

    p=0
    i=i+1
end do

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia. of j1
q=0;q1=0

do k=2,n
 i=k
    do j=2,n
        if(j .ne. i)then
        q1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
        end if
        i=i-1;j=j-1
offdia1(i,j)=-q1
q1=0
i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
end do

do i=1,38
do j=1,38
J1(i,j)=offdia1(i,j)+dia1(i,j)
end do
end do
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!dia. of j2
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,(n-m)
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
         p1=V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 p=p1+p
       end if

    end do

    dia2(i-1,i-1)=p+(2*V(i)*Yabs(i,i)*cos(angle(i,i)))
    p=0;

end do
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia. of j2
p1=0;

do k=2,n
 i=k
    do j=2,(n-m)
        if(j .ne. i)then
       p1=V(i)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j));
        end if
        i=i-1;j=j-1
offdia2(i,j)=p1
    p1=0;
    i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
end do

do i=1,(n-m-1)

   offdia2(i,i)=dia2(i,i)

end do
J2=offdia2
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!dia. of j3
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,(n-m)
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
          p1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 p=p1+p;
       end if
    end do
    i=i-1;
    dia3(i,i)=p
    p=0;
    i=i+1;
 end do
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia of j3
p=0;p1=0

do k=2,(n-m)
 i=k;
    do j=2,n
        if(j .ne. i)then
    p1=V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
        end if
     i=i-1;j=j-1
    offdia3(i,j)=-p1;
    p1=0;
    i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
end do

do i=1,(n-m-1)
      offdia3(i,i)=dia3(i,i)

end do
J3=offdia3
!!!!!!!!!!dia of j4
p=0;p1=0
do i=2,(n-m)
    do j=1,n
       if(j .ne. i)then
           p1=V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
 p=p1+p
       end if

    end do

    dia4(i-1,i-1)=-(2*V(i)*Yabs(i,i)*sin(angle(i,i)))-p
    p=0;p1=0
end do
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!off dia of j4
p1=0;p=0

do k=2,(n-m)
 i=k;
    do j=2,(n-m)
        if(j .ne. i)then
       p1=V(i)*Yabs(i,j)*sin(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j))
        end if
    i=i-1;j=j-1
    offdia4(i,j)=-p1
    p1=0;
    i=i+1;j=j+1
    end do
 end do

 do i=1,(n-m-1)
offdia4(i,i)=dia4(i,i);
 end do

J4=offdia4
!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!formation of final jacobian!!!!!!!!!!
Jac( 1:38, 1:38) = J1 (1:38,1:38)
Jac( 1:38,39:67) = J2 (1:38,1:29)
Jac(39:67, 1:38) = J3 (1:29,1:38)
Jac(39:67,39:67) = J4 (1:29,1:29)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!region ends
!$acc end region

end program load_flow
```

I am using PGI accelerator directives for parallelization but it is showing

> "Compiler failed to translate accelerator region (see -Minfo messages): Induction variable with zero step value"

Comment: too long to read, show only the relevant section

Comment: why not start by reducing the scope of $acc so that you can see where the error is coming from?  also, what does -Minfo show?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i edited.now i am showing only the region in which i want parallelization but it is showing error

Comment: What are -Minfo messages? Also, judging from the message you posted - it seems that some loop variable is not incremented. I know CUDA, but this is Fortran here. Why did you tagged as such?

Comment: I retagged it from accelerator to pgi-accelerator.  I also retitled it.  Note that PGI accelerator generates CUDA code, hence the CUDA tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not confident this will work, but it should be a step in the right direction:

```
!!!!!!!region starts 
p1=0;p=0
!$acc region do
do i=2,n
    do j=1,n
        p1=(V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j)))
        p=p1+p
     end do
     P0(i-1)=p
     p=0
end do
```

Comment: i tried.but it is showing "DO loop expected after ACC REGION DO"

Comment: I recommend you convert to OpenACC now that it is more mature (works with PGI compilers).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this to initialize p=0 at the top of the outer loop:

```
!!!!!!!region 
!$acc region do
do i=2,n
    p=0
    do j=1,n
        p1=(V(i)*V(j)*Yabs(i,j)*cos(angle(i,j)-d(i)+d(j)))
        p=p1+p
     end do
     P0(i-1)=p
end do
```